# How do I run an If function on a list of values to output another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, conditional

I'm so sorry that this is probably a basic question. I am a student and have 0 prior experience with Mathematica or any sort of coding and I have looked at various resources trying to figure it out myself but still need help.

I currently have a list of values (called "ProbSurvMale" in my code)

```
{{0.958598}, {0.694663}, {0.118085}, {0.390693}, {0.762198}, \
{1.55629*10^-6}, {0.0292393}, {0.320323}, {0.139982}, {0.809311}, \
{0.0993175}, {0.961641}, {0.033014}, {0.833012}, {0.125618}, \
{0.971254}, {0.000109839}, {0.116335}, {0.00260359}, {0.0837473}}
```

I also have a `RandomReal` function.

```
draw := RandomReal[{0, 1}]
```

My code for the `If` statement is

```
Contest := If[draw < x, "live", "ded"]
```

I want to run the `If` statement for every value in the ProbSurvMale list. I don't know how to apply it to the list. I tried `Contest @@@ ProbSurvMale`, which gave me

```
{"live"[0.00206366], "live"[0.000243393], "live"[0.118085], 
 "live"[0.390693], "live"[0.0451756], "live"[0.44083], 
 "live"[0.851076], "live"[0.0000135539], "live"[1.28328*10^-6], 
 "live"[0.0362936], "live"[0.560129], "live"[0.0130393], 
 "live"[0.000628627], "live"[0.000651911], "live"[0.493252], 
 "live"[0.0116439], "live"[0.579737], "live"[0.0000690552], 
 "live"[0.0110516], "live"[0.0837473]}
```

and I tried `Map[Contest, {ProbSurvMale}]`, which gave me

```
{"live"[{{0.00206366}, {0.000243393}, {0.118085}, {0.390693}, \
{0.0451756}, {0.44083}, {0.851076}, {0.0000135539}, {1.28328*10^-6}, \
{0.0362936}, {0.560129}, {0.0130393}, {0.000628627}, {0.000651911}, \
{0.493252}, {0.0116439}, {0.579737}, {0.0000690552}, {0.0110516}, \
{0.0837473}}]}
```

Also, "live" is a placeholder for now. I want the term to retain its original value if the If condition is true.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Contest[x_] := If[draw <x, "live", "ded"];
Map[Contest, ProbSurvMale, {-1}]
```

> {{"live"}, {"live"}, {"ded"}, {"live"}, {"ded"}, {"ded"}, {"ded"}, 
>   {"ded"}, {"ded"}, {"live"}, {"ded"}, {"live"}, {"ded"}, {"ded"},
>   {"ded"}, {"live"}, {"ded"}, {"ded"}, {"ded"}, {"ded"}}

```
Contest @@@ ProbSurvMale
```

> {"live", "live", "live", "ded", "live", "ded", "ded", "ded", "ded", 
>   "live", "ded", "live", "ded", "live", "ded", "live", "ded", "live", 
>   "ded", "ded"}

Comment: thank you so much! the first input worked! is there a way i can message you privately?

Comment: @missalyssa, thank you for the accept. You can post your questions here or open a chat room for extended discussions that will too long for the comments section.

Comment: I posted another question if you still happen to be online.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199835/how-can-i-pair-the-values-in-2-different-tables-of-the-same-length-together-to-m