# How can I pair the values in 2 different tables of the same length together to make a table with 2 variables {x, y}?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, output

I have 2 tables, the first called GenotypesMaleUp

```
GenotypesMaleUp = {2.04545, 1.80196, 1.70542, 1.78403, 1.79929, 1.91629, 1.82785, \
1.52171, 1.9913, 1.43151, 1.96283, 1.44868, 2.11816, 2.03117, \
2.16076, 1.55718, 1.74599, 2.41115, 1.96451, 2.20853}
```

and the second called SurvivorsMaleUp

```
SurvivorsMaleUp = {0.989309, 0, 0.636673, 0, 0.810913, 0.964202, 0.857113, 0, 0.999606, \
0, 0, 0.350838, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.414982, 0.99347, 0.79752}
```

They are both the same length. I want to join the first term of GenotypesMaleUp with the first term of SurvivorsMaleUp, and so on for each other term so it would look like

```
{2.04545,0.989309}, {1.80196,0},(1.70542,0.636673},...
```

I tried `Table[{GenotypesMaleUp, SurvivorsMaleUp}, 1]` but got

```
{{{2.04545, 1.80196, 1.70542, 1.78403, 1.79929, 1.91629, 1.82785, 
   1.52171, 1.9913, 1.43151, 1.96283, 1.44868, 2.11816, 2.03117, 
   2.16076, 1.55718, 1.74599, 2.41115, 1.96451, 2.20853}, {0.989309, 
   0, 0.636673, 0, 0.810913, 0.964202, 0.857113, 0, 0.999606, 0, 0, 
   0.350838, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.414982, 0.99347, 0.79752}}}
```

as the output, so it just joined the lists together at the end of the first and beginning of the second list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) after transforming each element of `GenotypesMaleUp` to a list:

```
Join[List /@ GenotypesMaleUp, SurvivorsMale, 2]
```

> {{2.04545, 0}, {1.80196, 0}, {1.70542, 0}, {1.78403, 
>     0.784521}, {1.79929, 0}, {1.91629, 0.964202}, {1.82785, 
>     0}, {1.52171, 0.304152}, {1.9913, 0}, {1.43151, 0}, {1.96283, 
>     0}, {1.44868, 0}, {2.11816, 0.929934}, {2.03117, 0}, {2.16076, 
>     0}, {1.55718, 0.36051}, {1.74599, 0}, {2.41115, 0}, {1.96451, 
>     0}, {2.20853, 0.79752}}

Alternatively, [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)  after [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)ning `SurvivorsMale`:

```
Transpose[{GenotypesMaleUp, Flatten@SurvivorsMale}]
```

> same result

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: is there a way (with a different table with 2 variables {x,y}, that i can isolate the first variable of each term to just have a list of {x1, x2,...}

Comment: So if I have DelZeroMale={{2.04545, 0.989309}, {1.70542, 0.636673}, {1.78403, 
  0.784521}, {1.9913, 0.999606}, {1.96283, 0.992836}, {1.44868, 
  0.205681}, {1.74599, 0.714837}, {2.20853, 0.79752}}   , how can I get {2.04545, 1.70542, 1.78403, ...} @kglr

Comment: @missalyssa, try `DelZeroMale[[All,1]]` (see [`Part ([[...]])`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) in the docs)

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!!! is there a way i can monetarily compensate you? (I feel like that's not allowed on the website but I am seriously so grateful) @kglr

Comment: @missalyssa, my pleasure. Re monetary compensation, the thought counts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Thread[{GenotypesMaleUp, SurvivorsMale}]
```